# Python BDD Test all data combinations

Tags: python, cucumber, bdd, gherkin, python-behave

Say I have two sets of test data for a BDD scenario.

dataX = [A, B, C]

dataY = [1, 2, 3, 4]

**How can I run a scenario against all combinations of dataX-dataY, without explicitly defining these combinations in the scenario outline?**

Currently, the BDD scenario looks something like the below, and as you can see I am explicitly defining all possible combinations. Things can become very impractical very quickly if the value count and/or variable count increase. Am using the `python-behave library` for this.

```
Scenario Outline: Test all data combinations - <dataX> <dataY>
    Given combination <dataX> <dataY>
    When do stuff with given combination <dataX> <dataY>
    Then check result for <dataX> <dataY>

 Examples: Input
 | dataX | dataY |
 |   A   |   1   |  
 |   A   |   2   | 
 |   A   |   3   | 
 |   A   |   4   | 
 |   B   |   1   |  
 |   B   |   2   | 
 |   B   |   3   | 
 |   B   |   4   | 
 |   C   |   1   |  
 |   C   |   2   | 
 |   C   |   3   | 
 |   C   |   4   |
```

Note this needs to be done via Scenario Outline & Examples to ensure all test data coverage. Using a simple Scenario and potentially testing all combinations under a single test is not sufficient, as it typically means the test stops at the first failure encountered, skipping any remaining test data.

Comment: If you need to have every combination executed as separate test with a status, then I am not sure there is a good way to do it in behave. Why not defining dataX and dataY params in 2 steps with setup tables and validate in the last one with combined results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through the guts of the `behave` library implementation, I was able to find some methods that one can use to do just this: build the `Examples` table programatically. My use case is the large number of data combinations that *all* need testing.

This goes in `environment.py`:

```
from behave.model import Scenario, Examples, Table
from itertools import product

def before_feature(context, feature):
    ...
    # data for each column for the Examples table; the way you get this is based on your specific case;
    # you can read it from a file or generate it etc.; this here is merely an example
    data_x = [data for test column dataX here]
    data_y = [data for test column dataY here]

    # create data tuples aka table rows; we will add these a bit later to the Examples table
    # the way you build this is also specific to your case; I am using itertools.product for a quick way to get all possible pairs
    all_data_pairs = [(dx, dy) for dx, dy in product(data_x, data_y)]

    # identify the behave.model.Examples object we will populate
    example: Examples = next(sc.examples[0] for sc in feature.scenarios if
                                     sc.name == 'Test all data combinations - <dataX> <dataY>')

    # Examples consists, amongst other things, of an object of type behave.model.Table
    test_table: Table = example.table
    
    # add test data to the Examples table, row by row
    for row in all_data_pairs:
        test_table.add_row(row)
```

This will ensure scenario `"Test all data combinations - <dataX> <dataY>"` asserts *all* test rows. It will NOT stop after the first failure.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but you can do a general scenario like this:

```
Feature: Test
Scenario: Test all data combinations
    Given combination data is loaded
    When combinations are processed
    Then display results
```

This would allow you to load your data in the first step (ex. from an external file) and do a combinatorial process in the When step (potentially calling other steps).

The step implementations could look like this:

```
from behave import *
from steps import data

@given('combination data is loaded')
def step_impl(context):
    context.data_x = getattr(data, "dataX")
    context.data_y = getattr(data, "dataY")
    print(context.data_x)
    print(context.data_y)

@when('combinations are processed')
def step_impl(context):
    for x in context.data_x:
        for y in context.data_y:
            context.execute_steps(
                """
                When process combination {x} and {y}
                Then check result for given combination
                """.format(x=x, y=y)
            )

@then('display results')
def step_impl(context):
    print(context.results)

@when('process combination {x} and {y}')
def step_impl(context, x, y):
    context.x = x
    context.y = y

@then('check result for given combination')
def step_impl(context):
    context.results.append('.'.join([context.x, context.y]))
```

Running this gives:

```
>>behave --no-capture
Feature: Test # test.feature:1

  Scenario: Test all data combinations  # test.feature:2
    Given combination data is loaded    # steps/step_implementation.py:4
['A', 'B', 'C']
[1, 2, 3, 4]
    When combinations are processed     # steps/step_implementation.py:20
    Then display results                # steps/step_implementation.py:31
['A.1', 'A.2', 'A.3', 'A.4', 'B.1', 'B.2', 'B.3', 'B.4', 'C.1', 'C.2', 'C.3', 'C.4']

1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
1 scenario passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
3 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m0.016s
```

Comment: Thanks Monica. It has to be done through `Scenario Outlines` unfortunately. This is to ensure all data coverage. If for example there is a failure point at A.3 and another one at B.2, approaching the test with a `Scenario` will reveal the failure at A.3 and stop. You will not know if/how many more failure points exist after A.3 this way. I have documented a solution that takes the input test data and builds the `Examples` table, as a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this differently. The purpose of BDD is to check the behaviour of the application and this can be done by testing with few specific set of data that tests the different business requirements. For an example, if the requirement is to add 2 numbers, you would test that with different set of data like positive, negative, decimal numbers. You wouldn't test with all possible number combination.

However, if your application does handle each data differently than yes you would have to test for all data combination. In this scenario, it is better to define the large dataset rather than writing the code to generate the data sets. The reason being, it is better to explicitly state what your application is going to process as part of your BDD steps rather than buried in the code, which is understood only by the technical members of the team. This defeats the purpose of using BDD.

For very large datasets, you could consider maintaining the data in excel. I have shown how this could be done in NoCodeBDD (Disclaimer: I am the founder of NoCodeBDD) https://nocodebdd.live/examples-using-excel.  You could do the same in Cucumber but you have to write the code to read the excel.

Comment: Thanks Jerome. It really is a case of having to test a large set of data (finite, but still large), while also ensuring all data is covered without stopping the run at the first failure. This second part of the requirement is addressed by using `Scenario Outlines` instead of `Scenarios`, so no concerns there. For the main issue I have documented my solution in a separate answer.

Comment: Pretty cool tool btw!